# Trying to list Watson Dialog Nodes, getting an error

Tags: node.js, ibm-watson, watson

I am trying to call IBM Watson using Node, in order to get the list of dialog nodes from my Workplace. I am using the listDialogNodes from the API documentation.

This is the code I am using:

```
var watson = require('watson-developer-cloud');

  var conversation = new watson.ConversationV1({
    username: USERNAME,
    password: PASSWORD,
    version_date: '2017-05-26'
  });

  var params = {
    workspace_id: WORKSPACE_ID,
  };

  conversation.listDialogNodes(params, function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
    } else {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
    }

  });
```

I keep getting the error 'conversation.listDialogNodes is not a function' even though this code is an example taken from the API page, save of course the USERNAME, PASSWORD and WORKSPACE_ID.

I have another method to send a message to Watson and that one is working fine, so it shouldn't be credentials or something like that.

Comment: I have tried your code with my credentials and it is working for me, i am using watson-developer-cloud 3.0.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just took the latest node-sdk (3.0.4) for **watson-developer-cloud** and checked the node-modules for it.
Surprisingly, IBM has made a joke out of it. In the node-modules the command to get the list of dialog nodes is `ConversationV1.prototype.getDialogNodes`(getDialogNodes) instead of `ConversationV1.prototype.listDialogNodes`(listDialogNodes) as mentioned in the documentation.

Once you change your code accordingly, it works smoothly.

```
conversation.getDialogNodes(params, function(err, response) {
if (err) {
  console.error(err);
} else {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
}
```